# Aggregate Query returns null array

Tags: mongodb

I have three collections in EmployeeDB.

1. Employee

```
{ 
    "user_id" : "EMP001", 
    "FirstName" : "Manoj", 
    "LastName" : "sharma", 
    "Status" : "0/1", 
    "CreateDate" : "1988-10-11T18:30:00.000Z"
}
```

2. EmpContact

```
{ 
    "user_id" : "EMP001", 
    "Phone" : "9999999999", 
    "Email" : "xyz@gmail.com"
}
```

3. EmpInfo

```
{ 
    "user_id" : "EMP001", 
    "Gender" : "Male", 
    "Age" : NumberInt(20), 
    "Designation" : "manager", 
    "Salary" : "5000"
}
```

I need to group the three collections and display all fields.
I tried the below code,

```
db.Employee.aggregate([
        {$lookup: {from: "EmpContact",localField: "user_id",foreignField: "user_id",as: "contact"}},
        {$unwind:"$EmpContact"},
        {$lookup: {from: "EmpInfo",localField: "user_id",foreignField: "user_id",as: "empinfo"}},
        {$unwind:"$EmpInfo"},
        {
            $match:{user_id : "EMP001"}
        }
]).toArray();
```

But I got an empty array, Please help me...

Comment: While using mongodb you should consider saving all the related information in the same collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from your `$unwind`.
Since you name your field as `contact` in the `$lookup`, the field `EmpContact` doesn't exist.
The same thing for the second `unwind`, `EmpInfo` doesn't exist but `empinfo` does

Here is the full query

```
db.Employee.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "EmpContact",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "contact"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$contact"
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "EmpContact",
      localField: "user_id",
      foreignField: "user_id",
      as: "empinfo"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$empinfo"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      user_id: "EMP001"
    }
  }
])
```

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pa9ECwube_Q)